# Matplotlib subfigures spacing and sizing

Tags: python, matplotlib

**I need:**

- a matplotlib figure consisting of two subfigures (let's say in a column)
- subfigure A to have `aspect` = `equal`
- both subfigures to have the same `width`
- to save the figure as `pgf`
- to set the figure's maximum size

**I would like:**

- to be able to set the height of subfigure B (either absolute or relative to A)
- to be able to set the space between A and B (either absolute or relative to A)

**The issues:**

- `ax.set_aspect('equal')` set for only one subfigure makes the width of A and B different
- if I set figure size using `plt.figure(figsize=(w,h))` and use the `pgf` backend the picture seems to adjust the gaps to fill the given size, I would like the picture to just scale down to fit into the given size, but not to stretch.
- <strike>**Edit:** I have just noticed that the labels with minus are not at the same baseline as those without minus. I am not sure if it is related.</strike> This issue seems to be on the pgf side.

Using a few answers from stackoverflow, I came up with this (A at bottom, B at top):

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

matplotlib.use('pgf')
matplotlib.rcParams.update({
    'text.usetex'     : True,
    'pgf.texsystem'   : 'pdflatex',
})

color_levels = 128
cmap = matplotlib.cm.RdBu_r
range_min = 0
range_max = np.pi

gkw = {'height_ratios':[0.03, 1] }
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 1, gridspec_kw = gkw)

lvlmax = 2
lvlmin = -2

ax = axs[1]
ax.set_xlim(range_min, range_max)
ax.set_ylim(range_min, range_max)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.grid(False)

X = np.linspace(range_min, range_max, color_levels)
Z = np.linspace(range_min, range_max, color_levels)
X, Z = np.meshgrid(X, Z)
val = np.power(np.sin(X), 2) + np.cos(Z)

cf = ax.contourf(X, Z, val, cmap=cmap, zorder=1, extend='both',
                 levels=np.linspace(lvlmin, lvlmax, color_levels, endpoint = True))

axes_ratio = gkw['height_ratios'][1]/gkw['height_ratios'][0]

# colorbar
ax = axs[0]
ax.set_xlim(lvlmin, lvlmax)
y_max = (lvlmax-lvlmin)/30
ax.set_ylim(0, y_max)
ax.grid(False)

X = np.tile(np.linspace(lvlmin, lvlmax, color_levels), (10, 1))
Z = np.transpose(np.tile(np.linspace(0, y_max, 10), (color_levels, 1)))
color = np.tile(np.linspace(lvlmin, lvlmax, color_levels), (10, 1))

cf = ax.contourf(X, Z, color, cmap=cmap, zorder=1,
                    levels=np.linspace(lvlmin, lvlmax, color_levels, endpoint = True))

ax.tick_params(left=False, right=False , top=True, bottom=False,
                labelbottom=False, labeltop=True, labelleft=False)

y_axis_length = np.diff(np.array(ax.get_ylim()))[0]
x_axis_length = np.diff(np.array(ax.get_xlim()))[0]
other_axis_aspect = axs[1].get_aspect()

ax.set_aspect((other_axis_aspect/axes_ratio)/(y_axis_length/x_axis_length))

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0.05)

boxes = [ax.get_tightbbox() for ax in axs]
aspect = ((max([b.y1 for b in boxes]) - min([b.y0 for b in boxes])) /
          (max([b.x1 for b in boxes]) - min([b.x0 for b in boxes])))
fig.set_size_inches(3.4, 3.4*aspect)

fig.canvas.draw()
fig.savefig(sys.argv[1], bbox_inches = 'tight', transparent = True)
```

This code produces:
[image: MWE output]

This solution works fine for most plots but sometimes the space between the subfigures is suddenly different. I guess that the tightbox may not always work as intended. Moreover, the code seems quite artificial and I guess/**hope there is a better approach**.

**Note:**
One of the subfigures in the MWE is a colorbar. I am aware of the dedicated command for this. The automatic colorbar also has some issues with the size, but, more importantly, for high number of contour levels, the colorbar is saved as `png` instead of `pgf`. Moreover, there are usecases for this question outside the colorbar.